# Loading EC keys in PEM format into an .Net Fx 4.8 application

Tags: c#, openssl, ecdsa, .net-4.8

I am trying to load an EC Private key from base64 string obtained from PEM file which was generated with openssl into a **netfx4.8 application** this is later used to create ECDsa key object.

I have noticed that we have a PEM reader in .Net5 so what are my options while staying in .Net4.8.

To make it clear we create keys with following openssl command

```
openssl ecparam -out ecc_private_key.key -name secp256r1 -genkey
```

which gives output into following format (This is an example key only - not used anywhere)

```
-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
BggqhkjOPQMBBw==
-----END EC PARAMETERS-----
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIBfBTJGdjFUK2S0bTBWfogeRElTF52jjVjeSs2GvsIrvoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEQEyYxahMyU6H7i4GkX0pzOtgNiJrwxLGSiLSgBgFjV/VfGIUjrQl
ia6+KPlQJd0IRtQLIG0kqXeD/yyeikuYBw==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So we like to inject base64 contents available within "EC PRIVATE KEY" header/footer into the application.

**Current workaround**
Currently I am using following command to parse the contents and then injecting Private and Public key separately. this helps to remove unwanted headers available in PEM contents.

```
$ openssl ec -in ecc_private_key.key -noout -text
read EC key
Private-Key: (256 bit)
priv:
    17:c1:4c:91:9d:8c:55:0a:d9:2d:1b:4c:15:9f:a2:
    07:91:12:54:c5:e7:68:e3:56:37:92:b3:61:af:b0:
    8a:ef
pub:
    04:40:4c:98:c5:a8:4c:c9:4e:87:ee:2e:06:91:7d:
    29:cc:eb:60:36:22:6b:c3:12:c6:4a:22:d2:80:18:
    05:8d:5f:d5:7c:62:14:8e:b4:25:89:ae:be:28:f9:
    50:25:dd:08:46:d4:0b:20:6d:24:a9:77:83:ff:2c:
    9e:8a:4b:98:07
ASN1 OID: prime256v1
NIST CURVE: P-256
```

Comment: I think previous to .Net5 everyone uses BouncyCastle for anything to do with PEM

Comment: I have looked at the bouncy castle Pem reader code and they have commented out for EC keys since it wasn't working as expected. I will double check and post the details here once get time for that.